# Contao 4.4 custom elements

Tags: element, contao

I recently switched from Contao 3.X to Contao 4.4. So far so good. I like it very much. Especially working with composer.

Currently, I am looking for a solution, to create custom content elements. In Contao 3.X I could do this with the extension `dma_elementgenerator` (https://github.com/DMAGmbH/dma_elementgenerator). Now it looks like it's deprecated and not usable in any Contao 4.X version.

Has anyone a solution (or at least an idea) how to create custom content elements?

Example: I have to display a section with some progress bars:

[image: progress bars]

I'm just looking for a way to manage those stats from the backend. Actually, I just need following custom fields:

- Title
- Percent
- Colour

I was looking for a possibility in the last few days, but I couldn't find any. If there is no direct solution: has anyone a tip/howto, so I can possibly create a new Contao 4 extension by myself?

Never created an extension in Contao 4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Received a solution from another forum. There is a way to install Contao 3.X extensions in Contao 4.X.

The how to is in german, but maybe someone will need it too:

https://www.marcosimbuerger.ch/contao-kurzanleitungen-details/contao-3-erweiterung-in-contao-4-installieren.html

Answer (score 2):

Currently you can use rocksolid custom-elements[1] by Martin Auswoeger.
He has already ported them to Contao 4.

Other extensions will follow soon.

If you really want to create your own extension, there is plenty of information available in German from various talks on the conference website, the website of the Contao Nordtag and so on.

Sadly almost none in English so far but we will change that.

For beginners, I always suggest to grab a small contao extension (nowadays called "contao-bundle") from github or packagist and read the code.

[1] https://github.com/madeyourday/contao-rocksolid-custom-elements